# Access HealthKit Step Counter Data inXcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, healthkit

I'm trying to use HealthKit's Step Counter function in my code. Can I read this directly from the Store, and how can I go about reading and displaying the step data?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple query and execute. [This article](http://natashatherobot.com/healthkit-getting-fitness-data/) has good information on how to query and read step data in HealthKit.

[Read more about HealthKit here.](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/)